# HTML Template not being returned in Google Apps Script GAS

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I have two files. The first one is a Google Script File (ReportEmail.gs) with the following code:

```
function doGet() {  
      var t= HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('EmailTemplate');
      var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var hoja=ss.getSheetByName("Email");
      t.BD=hoja.getRange(1,1,hoja.getLastRow(),hoja.getLastColumn()).getValues();
      t.totalCols=hoja.getLastColumn();
      t.totalRows=hoja.getLastColumn();
      return t.evaluate().getContent(); 
 }
```

The second one is the HTML template (EmailTemplate.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>

  <?for(var i=0; i<2; i=i+2){
    if(BD[4][i+1]=="YES" && BD[0][i]>0){?>
      <p><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><strong><?= BD[2][i] ?></strong></span></p>
      <ul>
      <?for(var j=5; j<BD[0][i]+5; j+1){?>
        <li><?= BD[j][i] ?></li>
      <?}?>
      </ul>
    <?}?>
  <?}?>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I run the doGet function the script gets stuck and seems to be in a loop forever in the line "return t.evaluate().getContent();". I don't have a spreadsheet with lots of data either. Please help me find the problem! Very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I got it. It was a problem in the second for, it should say j++ and not j+1.